# Вместо null в таблицу вставляется 0000:00:00

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Всем добрый вечер,
Я с помощью php вставляю в БД данные, вот таким образом :

```
INSERT INTO TarificationLogs(serviceID, msisdn, msisdnType, currentStatus, datetimeStarted, datetimeTrialEnded, datetimeStoped, datePaidUntil, datetimeLastCharge, datetimeLastSuccessCharge, langID, isSubscribedAtOperatorSide, url, response) VALUES('100','37433555425','UNKNOWN','SUSPEND','2021-02-18 13:54:49','NULL','NULL','2022-03-12','2021-08-19 13:15:13','2021-07-23 00:59:58','','0','test','NULL')
```

И в БД всё выгдлядит так :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так что-бы вместо 0000:00:00 был null?
И да, изменить запрос не получится, так как мы не знаем какая именно значение null а какая нет.
Вот структура БД

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как думаете, между `NULL` и `'NULL'` есть разница?

Comment: если вы что-то не знаете, то надо проверить и выяснить. А вообще надо вообще не подставлять значения напрямую в текст запроса, а использовать нормальную передачу параметров.

Comment: @teran какой агресивный коментатор, я знаю что `NULL` это пустота, а `'NULL'` это строка

Comment: @teran просто у меня голова кипит )

Comment: так если знаете что `'null'` это не `null`, то зачем пихаете это в запрос, тем более в поле даты?

Comment: @teran дела в том что я не знаю кода эта значение будет `NULL` или нет, это просто пример, может быть случаё когда все поля полные и не присуствует ни один `NULL`

Comment: @teran возможно я вас запутал и извиняюсь, всем доброго вечера

Comment: тогда повторюсь, почитайте про передачу параметров в запрос. обычно пишут `insert into x (field) values (:f)` и передают массив `['f' => ....]`, СУБД там уже сама сделает остальное за вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у меня есть несколько идей

`COALESCE(col,'0000:00:00')` -  принимает первое ненулевое значение 
`create triger`  - проверить нулевой столбец при вставке

```
INSERT INTO TarificationLogs(serviceID, msisdn, msisdnType, currentStatus, datetimeStarted, datetimeTrialEnded, datetimeStoped, datePaidUntil, datetimeLastCharge, datetimeLastSuccessCharge, langID, isSubscribedAtOperatorSide, url, response) VALUES('100','37433555425','UNKNOWN','SUSPEND','2021-02-18 13:54:49','NULL','NULL','2022-03-12','2021-08-19 13:15:13','2021-07-23 00:59:58','','0','test',COALESCE('NULL','0000:00:00'))
```

**будет задано значение по умолчанию, но, к сожалению, оно получит нулевое значение.**

Comment: там написано "чтобы вместо 00000 было null", а не наоборот

Comment: ДА Я СДЕЛАЛ ОШИБКУ